# syntax error in validation array in cakephp model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a syntax error in validation array in model. Its ok if I write the same code in controller

```
$validation = array(
       'field' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'field Can not be empty!'
            ),
            'validRange' => array(
                'rule' => array('comparison', '>', __('MAX_RANGE'))), //here is the syntax error. MAX_RANGE is a constant which is define in language file 
                'message' => 'field cant not be greater than maximum range'
            )
 )
)
```

Comment: What is the error message? How have you included this in your model?

Comment: syntax error `unexpected '('`

Comment: Start counting parentheses, then.

Comment: Or use an editor with proper syntax highlighting? :) phpstorm would have shown this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you get these kind of errors, i too will recommend you to start the paranthesis .

Here it is

**field** will have the array

```
'field' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'field Can not be empty!'
            )
```

**validRange** has

```
validRange' => array(
                'rule' => array('comparison', '>', __('MAX_RANGE')), 
                is define in language file 
                'message' => 'field cant not be greater than maximum range'
            )
```

And you missed the `rule` inside

```
'rule' => array('comparison', '>', __('MAX_RANGE')),
```

So, at the end you will be having

```
<?php
    $validation = array(
           'field' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'field Can not be empty!'
                )),
                'validRange' => array(
                    'rule' => array('comparison', '>', __('MAX_RANGE')), //here the syntax error should have gone :p
                    'message' => 'field cant not be greater than maximum range')
                );
?>
```

Comment: actually validRange is not the field name. let field name is `charge`. Now I want to validate this field with two validation rule one is it cant not be empty and it can not be greater then maximum range

Comment: Are you getting any error now ? or You need to know how you rule can be changed ?

Answer (score -1):

Hello Try This code once

`$validation = array(
       'field' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'field Canenter code here not be empty!'
            ),
            'validRange' => array(
                'rule' => array('comparison', '>', __('MAX_RANGE')), //here is the syntax error. MAX_RANGE is a constant which is define in language file 
                'message' => 'field cant not be greater than maximum range'
            )
       )
 )`